# Acting on multiple status changes with Nifi Expression Language

Tags: bigdata, etl, apache-nifi

I have an "UpdateAttribute" processor that evaluates information in a JSON file. Originally, this would just check if a client had been updated and the statement looked something like this:

```
${literal(${allAttributes("client_attribute1", "client_attribute2"):equals("UPDATED")}):ifElse("UPDATED","UNCHANGED")}
```

However, the specifics of the client's status change now needs to be tracked - such that if the client goes from OFFLINE to ONLINE, then their status is "1". If they go from ONLINE to OFFLINE, then their status is "3". This would ideally be done in a single statement. I'm not sure exactly how this would work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be better to use **UpdateAttribute processor Advanced usage** for this case.

Add all **your rules you need to check** then **add the attribute** which satisfied your rule.

Refer to [this](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html) and [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/141774/how-to-generate-a-variable-under-conditions-for-an.html) links for more details regards to UpdateAttribute Advanced usage.